# Is it possible to filter off Old Value or New Value in a history report ?

Tags: history-tracking

I have built a report with the [Object Name] Field History report type which is automatically created upon enabling history tracking in an object, but I am unable to use Old Value or New Value in the report filters. My goal is to create a report which shows a specific Old Value which was changed to a specific New Value.

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: Are you just trying to figure out how often that happened? You could certainly run a query and export it via workbench, for example.

Comment: Yha, for instance - I'm trying to figure out when a Status__c field was changed from "Unassigned" to "Assigned". If I can see that then I could report on the number of times a specific user had done that. But if I can't use Old Value and New Value in a filter then I can't specify those values as the only which show up in the report. I suppose exporting is the only route I available...?

Comment: Are you open to adding a field to track it? Populating it via trigger (or more appropriately a declarative alternative) would be trivial. The backfill batch would be pretty straightforward in its own right.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - my guess is you are referring to the same method brovasi is referring to below ?

Comment: No, not really. I'm saying add a `Datetime` field to flag when it was changed, or if you want to track by whom, add a `Lookup`.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little confused because I am working with a custom object named Task__c (not to be confused by the standard object). I am creating a report using the report type "Task History", which I am assuming was automatically created when the field tracking was activated with the Task__c custom object. When I create the reports I have History Data (Old Value & New Value). So where am I supposed to create the new fields ? I don't see a corresponding object specifically for the history fields, is there ?

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to filter on Old Value/New Value. But I really like this idea. Here is what Salesforce is proposing you :

> Currently, there is no ability to filter on the Old Value or New Value
>   in a history report, however there are 2 work arounds.
>
> 1. Use the Analytic Snapshot aka reporting snapshot and create the report off of the Target Object.  Please see "Prepare Reporting
>      Snapshots" in Help and Training to learn how to setup up an Analytic
>      Snapshot.  When you get to Step 3: Create fields on the target object,
>      create two text fields called "Old Value" and the other "New Value".
>      After the snapshot has run, create a report off of the Target Object
>      and then add a criteria for the "Old Value" and "New Value" into your
>      new report.
>
> **NOTE:  This only applies to new data and will not report
>   on previous data.  Also, 2000 records is the maximum returned per
>   snapshot.**
>
> 2. Export the report into Excel to filter on the Old Value or New Values.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005966&language=en_US

PS: I also invite you to vote for the [idea on IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6PSAAY)

Comment: thank you very much. I'm assuming the new "Old Value" and "New Value" fields I will be creating are formula (text) fields ? Otherwise, I'm wondering how they get the values of the original Old Value & New Value fields.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been delivered in Summer '18. Documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_filter_old_value_new_value.htm&type=5

Comment: N.B. sadly - still not available in SOQL